# How do I make a "Update every 1/10 second" function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make the worst cookie clicker game possible but I can't figure out how to make a update every 1/10 second in python. plz help (im not using pygame btw)

```
from tkinter import *
import time

points = 0
money = 0
bonus = 0

def click(points,money):
    points += bonus
    money += points

def update():
    #help me i dont know anything about this type of function
    pass

game = Tk()


cookies= Label(game, text=f'Cookies: {money}',font=(14)).grid(row=0,column=0)
cookie = Button(game,text='\nCookie\n',font=(20),command=lambda :click(points,money)).grid(row=1,column=0)

update()

game.mainloop()
```

I don't really know how to make this type of function but I want it to update the game 10 times every second so if you click the "cookie" it will add one to the score. (im not done with the game yet so all i have is the cookie and the score)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you run your own code alongside Tkinter's event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use method after like below:

```
def update():
    #help me i dont know anything about this type of function
    game.after(100, update)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Tkinter [`after`](https://coderslegacy.com/python/tkinter-after/) method is used to trigger a function after a certain amount of time.

**(It calls the function only once)**

The function takes 3 main arguments:

1. The which the after method is called on (passes automatically by `widget.after()`
2. The time delay until the functions is called (in ms).

   > Tkinter only guarantees that the callback will not be called earlier than that; if the system is busy, the actual delay may be much longer.

   (from [Basic Widget Methods](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112021403id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method))
3. The function that should be called after that period of time

If you want to call your `update` function `10` times in a `second`, you can use the `after` function like so:

```py
def update():
    # The rest of your update code
    game.after(100, update)
```

- Passing `100` to the ms delay argument because `1000 ms in a sec`, `1000 / 10 = 100`.
- Passing `update` to the function argument so it will repeat itself.